# Can I create a directive that will allow me to create a HTML content block?

Tags: angularjs

I have code like this:

```
       <div>
            <span>Type</span>
            <select id="contentTypeSelect"
                    ng-change="home.configChanged(true)"
                    ng-model="ctrl.configService.admin.contentTypeId"
                    ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in ctrl.contentType.dataPlus">                   </select>
        </div>
```

It's very simple HTML but enclosing a `<select>` in a `<div>` with a `<span>` in that position is something I do many times. Is there a way I could create a directive that I could call like this and still have all the scopes working correctly in the actual HTML that the directive produces.

```
       <div data-form-select>
          label='Type'
          id="contentTypeSelect"
          ng-change="home.configChanged(true)"
          ng-model="ctrl.configService.admin.contentTypeId"
          ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in ctrl.contentType.dataPlus"
       </div>
```

One more question. If I do this then is this something that's commonly done? I would like to abide by best practices and so far I have not really found many good examples of using Directives to do what I would like to do.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this one is common for working all the directive

js file

```
angular.module("directiveAPP", [])
    .controller("directiveController", function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    var admin = [];
    var configService = {
        "admin": admin
    };
    var contentType = {
        "dataPlus": [{
            "id": 1,
                "name": "ABC"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
                "name": "DEF"
        }, {
            "id": 3,
                "name": "GHI"
        }]
    };
    $scope.home = {};
    $scope.ctrl = {
        "configService": configService
    };
    $scope.ctrl.configService.admin["contentTypeId"] = 0;
    $scope.ctrl["contentType"] = contentType;
    $scope.home.configChanged = function (data) {                
    };
}).directive("formSelect", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            label: '=',
            id: '=',
            ngChange: "&",
            ngModel: "=",
            options:"="
        },
        template: '<div><span>{{label}}</span><select id="{{id}}" ng-change="ngChange()" ng-model="ngModel" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in options"></div>',
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {            
            $scope.label = $attrs.label;
            $scope.id = $attrs.id;            
        }
    };
});
```

html file

```
<div ng-app="directiveAPP">
     <div ng-controller="directiveController">
          <data-form-select 
                data-label="Type" 
                data-id="contentTypeSelect" 
                data-ng-change="home.configChanged(true)" 
                ng-model="ctrl.configService.admin.contentTypeId" 
                data-options="ctrl.contentType.dataPlus"></data-form-select>                  
{{ctrl.configService.admin.contentTypeId}}
       <div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.contentType.dataPlus | filter:{'id':ctrl.configService.admin.contentTypeId}">
       id : {{item.id}}</br>
       name : {{item.name}}
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[***FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/RajamohanShilpa/fr7sn3d5/)

Comment: I didn't read the code properly - it looks ok. I still think that it could be simplified a lot, but I take back my earlier comments.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Josep's comment, yes you can and here is an example that will do what you want it to.

The key thing to share scope is to declare `scope:false` inside the directive. This means you will use the parent scope. Then all you need to do is include the template you need. e.g.

```
.directive('dataFormSelect', function() {
    return {
      scope: false,
      replace: true,
      template: '<div>\
        <span>Type</span>\
        <select id="contentTypeSelect"\
                ng-change="home.configChanged(true)"\
                ng-model="ctrl.configService.admin.contentTypeId"\
                ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in ctrl.contentType.dataPlus">\
        </select>\
      </div>'
    };
});
```

To use, you would just have this:

```
<div data-form-select>
</div>
```

As you have declared all the other ng attributes inside the directive

Comment: Thanks. This would work good but only for one control. All my select controls have different inputs so I need a solution like the answer I accepted.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the CaspNZ answer you can separate out concerns means that presentation html like this:

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'my-directive-content.html'
    };
  });
```

Then you need my-directive-content.html

```
       <div>
        <span>Type</span>
        <select id="contentTypeSelect"
                ng-change="home.configChanged(true)"
                ng-model="ctrl.configService.admin.contentTypeId"
                ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in ctrl.contentType.dataPlus">
        </select>
      </div>
```

And then you can you this "my-directive" custom directive in your angular application.